# In VBA, how do I dynamically assign sheets to a sheets collection

Tags: excel, vba, collections

The following code works:

```
    Dim shts As Sheets
    Set shts = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
```

What I would like to do is add sheets that may be created in the future to the **shts** collection.  The way I thought this would be accomplished involves using a loop where the sheet names are joined in a large string, making sure to obey the same formatting as in the example above.  This is my non-working code:

```
    Dim shts As Sheets
    Dim wks() As Worksheet
    Dim str As String
    
    ReDim wks(0 To Sheets.Count)
    Set wks(0) = Sheets(1)
    
    str = wks(0).Name & """"
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(wks)
        Set wks(i) = Sheets(i)
        str = str & ", """ & wks(i).Name & ""
    Next i
        
    Set shtsToProtect = Sheets(Array(str)) ' ERROR
    [Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range]
```

I've tried several variants of the string argument, still no luck.

Comment: I can't see any reason to do this. If you just want all sheets to be in a collection, that is the builtin Sheets collection.

Comment: In other words `Dim shts as Collection;  Set shts = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`  allows you to access all the worksheets  in your workbook.

Comment: @topsail Sorry, I didn't say it in my post, but the purpose is to create a subset of the sheets, not a set of all the sheets.  The operations being performed are not meant to be applied to all, just some.  Besides this, I'm not restricted to only this option to do what I need to do, but it's an opportunity to learn more about the language.

Comment: Well, there is really no way to "automatically" create an array of a subset of sheets - how would that code know what sheets to include/exclude? Unless you have some rule to apply. If you really wanted to do that (I don't suggest it) you would have to hook into the workbook worksheet add events (and probably delete events too, ultimately), and have some kind of class object that can hold this information at the workbook level. But it's hard to see how that would be an improvement over just using the builtin collection. Also you really must to ask the question you *really* have.

Comment: This might be a place to look at to get started (about intercepting when new sheets are added to a workbook). You can use the ThisWorkbook module as a place for this type of work (and accessing such data from other modules). More than that is hard to explain - SO is more about answer specific questions. Anyhow, here: [vba_events.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_events.htm) and here: [vba-workbook-events](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/vba-workbook-events/)  From there, you can get ideas what to look for.

Comment: I didn't say that I'm attempting to create an array of a subset of sheets.  I'm declaring a variable of type Sheets, and using the Array function to tell my assignment statement which sheet names I'm looking to use, which are in turn used by the Sheets object to complete the assignment.  The issue is that some of this subset will include sheets created during run-time.  Which is why my original statement above "Set shts = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")) is insufficient.

Comment: Are you trying at run-time to add all the (work)sheets (objects) or (work)sheet names in the workbook containing this code, to a collection (called `shtsToProtect`)? What will be the purpose of this collection? Depending on your answer, you might choose a different data structure e.g. an array or a dictionary or just use the built-in *Sheets* or *Worksheets* collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the subset sheets name into a string separated by given delimiter and then use `Split()` function to get an array out of it

```
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook
    
        Dim shSubSetNames As String
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        For Each sh In .Worksheets
        
            If sh.Name Like "Sheet*" Then ' change criteria as per your needs
            
                shSubSetNames = shSubSetNames & sh.Name & "|"
                
            End If
        
        Next
        
            If shSubSetNames <> vbNullString Then
            
                shSubSetNames = Left$(shSubSetNames, Len(shSubSetNames) - 1)
        
                    Dim subSetShts As Sheets
                        Set shts = Sheets(Split(shSubSetNames, "|"))
                    
                        shts.Select
        
            End If
    
    End With    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution to directly get to your goal, based on the code you wrote so far. You probably need to realize that having an array of worksheet names is not the same as only a string of names separated by commas. The latter is still just a string, not an array.

```
Sub Foo()

Dim i As Long
Dim shts() As String

ReDim shts(1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    shts(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
Next i

Worksheets(shts).Select

End Sub
```

But as noted in the comments, there is something much simpler you can do:

```
Sub Bar()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I realized after seeing the comments that I had not specified that I am looking to create a subset of my workbook's sheets.  I've used these collections for that before, but in the previous cases I didn't need it to be dynamic.  Also, I know that I can just add sheets to an array and perform my operation in a for loop, I'm just interested in this methodology because it helps me understand VBA better.